# Requesting LORs from the same recommenders for a different field

Tags: recommendation-letter

I might be in a rather unique situation. I earned my bachelor’s degree from my university in May 2014. Since my junior year of university, I was convinced that I wanted to take the LSAT and apply to law school. I had originally planned to apply to law school in the first semester of my senior year and start attending in fall 2015. However, after taking my first LSAT in October 2013, I decided to focus on my senior-year GPA instead of spending the entire fall semester studying for the LSAT. I retook the LSAT after graduating and applied to a few different law schools. I always knew that law school was expensive, and I heard that it is useless to go to law school these days unless it is a prestigious school. After getting accepted to a law school, I made the ultimate decision to not pursue a legal education mainly due to financial reasons and job prospects. The school only offered to give me loans and gave me only two weeks for an enrollment decision after emailing me the acceptance letter. 
I changed my career path and will apply to a few different master’s programs in the field I would now like to study.

Currently, I am working at a part-time job, while making preparations to apply to graduate school this fall. When I was applying to law school last fall, I had requested recommendation letters from two different professors. I am just wondering, but would it be possible to ask these same professors again for recommendation letters? Would they think that I look like an undecided, wavering person and thus, be reluctant to write another letter for me? Also, would I just candidly explain my one-year gap after my graduation in my statement of purpose?

Comment: A professor who cared about you will be happy that you have come up with a way you think will work for you to embark on new and exciting studies.  //  Also remember that parents (mostly women, but men more and more often) face gaps in employment and studies all the time, and Academia has learned to deal with it.  It's okay to have a gap.  This isn't a race.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible to ask these same professors again for recommendation letters?

Yes, it is possible.

> Would they think that I look like an undecided, wavering person and thus, be reluctant to write another letter for me?

If they don't want to write another letter, they can decline.  You can briefly explain what you've been up to and should explain briefly why you decided to pursue the new field of study.  It's possible your recommenders might see you as having stronger skills for the new field than for law, in which case your letter might actually be stronger than before.  Much of what they wrote might be general enough that they won't have to change much from the prior letter if they do choose to write you a new one.

> Also, would I just candidly explain my one-year gap after my graduation in my statement of purpose?

In your statement of purpose, while not trying to hide or paper over your one-year gap, focus on why you want to move forward in the direction you're applying for.  If you had experiences or learned things in that one year that helped inspire, drive, or prepare you for that field, it may be helpful to mention them.  Help your reader understand *why* you want to work in the field you're applying for, and think about what those reasons are (esp. if you have reasons that go beyond just job prospects).